# Bulk Data InsertQuery error in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a .csv file that i need to insert into database table using.Here is the query that i am  using ..

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\Users\vikas\Desktop\UserDetails.txt' INTO employee_users  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY ''(@UserName,@EmpID,@DepName,@MailId,@MonthlyQuota)
```

But i am getting error.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'employee_users  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY ''(@UserName,@EmpI' at line 1
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding table before employee_users

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\Users\vikas\Desktop\UserDetails.txt' INTO TABLE employee_users FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY ''(@UserName,@EmpID,@DepName,@MailId,@MonthlyQuota)
```

Syntax Reference: [LOAD DATA INFILE SYNTAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)